# Play Framework 1.2.4 Scheduled Jobs

Tags: playframework-1.x, job-scheduling

The question might sound very silly but here it is,

Are the scheduled jobs in play framework triggered automatically or do they need to be called from some place, say may be from application start up or so?
Or does it need any kind of configuration to be done except the scheduled time which in my case is

```
"@On("0 40 12 ? * MON-FRI")"
```

Please revert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jobs are triggered automatically. You can also invoke them manually, for example from another controller, by invoking the now() method on an Job instance. Have a look at http://playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/jobs#scheduling for more details.